# How to split text of a dataframe column into multiple columns?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to retrieve a string from an excel sheet and split it into words then print it or write it back into a new string but when retrieving the data using pandas and trying to split it an error occurs saying dataframe doesn't support split function

**the excel sheet has this line in it:**

[image]

**I expect and output like this:**

[image]

```py
import numpy
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('eng.xlsx')
txt = df

x = txt.split()

print(x)


AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are applying `split()` function on a DataFrame and that's not possible.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def append_nan(x, max_len):
    """
    Function to append NaN value into a list based on a max length
    """
    if len(x) < max_len:
        x += [np.nan]*(max_len - len(x))
    return x

# I define here a dataframe for the example
#df = pd.DataFrame(['This is my first sentence', 'This is a second sentence with more words'])
df = pd.read_excel('your_file.xlsx', index=None, header=None)
col_names = df.columns.values.tolist()
df_output = df.copy()

# Split your strings
df_output[col_names[0]] = df[col_names[0]].apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
# Get the maximum length of all yours sentences
max_len = max(map(len, df_output[col_names[0]]))

# Append NaN value to have the same number for all column
df_output[col_names[0]] = df_output[col_names[0]].apply(lambda x: append_nan(x, max_len))

# Create columns names and build your dataframe
column_names = ["word_"+str(d) for d in range(max_len)]
df_output = pd.DataFrame(list(df_output[col_names[0]]), columns=column_names)

# Then you can save it
df_output.to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

Comment: that was perfect for me, but how to retrieve sentences from the excel sheet rather than writing the sentences by my self

Comment: Same as you did using `df.read_excel()` and removing my line where I define the dataframe with text.

Comment: sorry for bothering when Im trying to add the Excel in place of your sentence it gives me error,                                    data=pd.read_excel('eng.xlsx',"Sheet1")
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_output = df.copy()

Comment: Which error? It's probably because you need to change the column name

Comment: my column doesnt have a name the excel file just have 2 columns in it which is first line and second line longer, the error is  KeyError: 0

Comment: Yeah that's what I said. Columns bale error. You dataframe always have column names. You can get them using `df.columns`

Comment: so I should write, data=pd.read_excel('eng.xlsx',"Sheet1") df = pd.DataFrame(data) df=df.columns()  df_output = df.copy(), sorry if its totally wrong but im still trying to learn it

Comment: still gives me same error I'm doing something wrong if you can help me with it will be really thank full

Comment: Try at least to understand the code I wrote, if you had search on SO the error you would have understand that it is a KeyError, means `0` is not a valid column name. I edited my post, it should work now.